# What was the meaning of Q's cryptic comment?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-q

After Q freezes the crewman/ensign/whatever in "[Encounter at Farpoint](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Encounter_at_Farpoint_(episode))," Picard insists that he wouldn't have been harmed: the phaser was set to stun. Q then states something along the lines of, "Would you want to be taken defenseless, captain?" I forgot his exact words, but it was something like that.

In-universe, I suppose Q was playing with the crew. Q isn't always straightforward, of course. Out-of-universe, I think maybe Q's character hadn't been fully fleshed out, and this was bad writing.

I prefer in-universe explanations.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Picard says that Q was in no danger because the crewman only had his phaser set on stun.

Q tells him that given that they *both* know how dangerous and savage humans are, that even being stunned is something to be frantically avoided, even to the point of defending oneself with lethal force.

> **Q:** *Knowing humans as thou dost, Captain, wouldst thou be captured helpless by them?*
>
> [e.g. Knowing humans as you do, Captain, would you want to be held captive and at their mercy]?

---

Obviously *we* know now that Q is essentially invulnerable but at the time it was not as clear.

Comment: In other words, he's making a show of it to emphasize the implicit violence of the crewman's action?

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish - Very much so. His entire premise is that humanity is barbaric and untrustworthy